# Using Ubuntu 20.04 current. mouse cursor keeps disappearing - wired and bluetooth. requires touching screen to reactivate

Tags: mouse, cursor

Using Ubuntu 20.04 current.  mouse cursor keeps disappearing - wired and bluetooth.  requires touching screen to reactivate.

Comment: From your question. Using Ubuntu 20.04 current What does this mean? That and there is no info here that can be used to even guess what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Modern mouse interfaces cater automatically for a sleep mode which will act as yours is doing.
The solution is not in Ubuntu but in the Mouse Driver where you should be able to switch off the sleep option.